# How to store each record or row in descending order into database in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to store a record or row in descending order of scores of match into database in ruby on rails. So that I can easily get top 3 topper as well as rank of current user. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: It would be better if you order records when you make `SELECT` from `db`, because, every time you want to store some records you have to sort them in order, then store. Fetch all records then sort them, then store.

Comment: The pattern used in Rails (and relational databases generally) is that we **do not care** what order records go into the database.  Instead, when you retrieve the records you can order them by a given field or combination of fields.  Do you have a specific reason to not want to use this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple: you don't need to specify any order when you insert data in a database. The database engine is capable of sorting the data according to your instructions when you perform the select.

Simply create a Rails model where you store the `score` and the reference of the subject associated with the score (e.g. the user_id).

Then, the solution is a simply as selecting the records ordering by score. Assuming your model is called `Result`

```
Result.order("score DESC").limit(3)
```

---

Just a small note. This is a very simple problem, as long as you have the necessary basic knowledge of Ruby, Rails and database interaction.

This answer will be helpful if you do. If you don't, you'll probably need to start from simpler problems to learn these topics first.

Comment: I'd also add a descending index on the score potentially.  add_index(:results, [:score], order: {score: desc})